# Change 'python' to point to python2.7 inside virtualenv

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, virtualenv, bazel

I'm trying to bazel build a target inside a virtualenv, and I'm coming across the following error:

```
Use --sandbox_debug to see verbose messages from the sandbox
Error occurred while attempting to use the default Python toolchain (@rules_python//python:autodetecting_toolchain).
According to '/home/vagrant/venv/bin/python -V', version is 'Python 3.7.5', but we need version 2. PATH is:

/home/vagrant/venv/bin:/home/vagrant/.local/bin:/home/vagrant/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin:/home/vagrant/bin

Please ensure an interpreter with version 2 is available on this platform as 'python2' or 'python', or else register an appropriate Python toolchain as per the documentation for py_runtime_pair (https://github.com/bazelbuild/rules_python/blob/master/docs/python.md#py_runtime_pair).

Note that prior to Bazel 0.27, there was no check to ensure that the interpreter's version matched the version declared by the target (#4815). If your build worked prior to Bazel 0.27, and you're sure your targets do not require Python 2, you can opt out of this version check by using the non-strict autodetecting toolchain instead of the standard autodetecting toolchain. This can be done by passing the flag `--extra_toolchains=@rules_python//python:autodetecting_toolchain_nonstrict` on the command line or adding it to your bazelrc.
```

I tried the `--extra_toolchains=@rules_python//python:autodetecting_toolchain_nonstrict` flag, but the build still failed after, so I thought I'd try building with python2 involved.

Current state of my system:

- Inside virtualenv:

  - `python` and `python3` seems to resolve to version 3.7.5
  - `python2` doesn't resolve to anything
  - `python2.7` resolves to python 2.7.17
- Outside virtualenv:

  - `python` resolves to 2.7.17
  - `python3` resolves to 3.7.5
  - `python2` doesn't resolve to anything
  - `python2.7` resolves to python 2.7.17

I want either `python` or `python2` in my virtualenv to resolve to 2.7.17 as well. (I think maybe `python2` is safer? I worry changing `python` can have a lot of other side-effects). For changing `python` I tried the "sudo update-alternatives" command several times, but it seems to already be pointing to the right thing. It seems like virtualenv just isn't picking it up. Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: How did you create the virtual environment?

Comment: You define which Python version you want when you _create_ your virtualenv. How exactly to do that with Python 2.7 depends on whether you have the `virtualenv` package installed for Python 2.